# Tapping a google map marker that updates a View causes map to "reset"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using an `onMarkerClick Listener` and updating `textviews` and `imageviews` depending on the marker that is clicked.  For some markers, I don't perform the update and in those cases, the zoom level, map centering etc works perfectly for my map (it doesn't change).  However, when I do perform an update to one of my Views, the map zooms out to how it was originally loaded and positions itself to its original spot.

I'm doing everything on the same thread.  If that could be the issue, how can I move the google map to a different thread?  If that's not the issue, what else could it be?

here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
if(marker.equals(markers.get(0).marker))
tv.setText("blah");
}
```

EDIT: update, I created a new thread using a handler to update the text, and it's still resetting the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the globallayoutlistener.  I removed it after the view was painted and all is hunkey dorey.